# Why does the usage of single brackets not throw an error when enumerating multiple columns after resample ()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can somebody explain me why the resample method tolerates both single and double brackets when used to group a data frame on multiple columns ?

I have tried the following statements:

```
yearly = merged.resample("A",on="Date")["mpg","Price"].mean()

yearly = merged.resample("A",on="Date")[["mpg","Price"]].mean()
```

Both statements return me a data frame regardless of using single brackets (Statement 1) or double brackets (Statement 2).

When using subsetting the source data frame "merged" directly on multiple columns, subsetting with single brackets does not work

```
merged[["mpg","Price"]] > works fine 

merged["mpg","Price"] > throws an error
```

Comment: What's `merged`? Are you speaking of pandas data frames? If so, add relevant tags.

Comment: I assume you're using Pandas so I added the [tag:pandas] tag to the question. If that's wrong, you can [edit] to fix. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: `["mpg","Price"]` this is select the column to pass the mean , when you do `merged[["mpg","Price"]]` is to select the column to filter